# How to answer the sentence "how are you going?"

Tags: phrase-choice

I found the following dialogue somewhere. The answer given is C. I am a little bit confused about it.

> - How are you going, buddy?
> - `________`. A little busy, though.

The options given for the blank were:

A. Not too bad
B. Can't be worse
C. On my own
D. By train

I want to know which answer is the best one.

Comment: You need to be a little more clear about the English question you are asking here. Yes, the phrase "how are you" can be interpreted in multiple ways, but an unanswerable multiple choice question is not the right way to inquire about that. P.S. Did you make up this question? Or find it somewhere?

Comment: "The best one" is rather subjective. The first two answers are not synonym, and it's not possible to say which one is better. I have never hear the other two answers; probably "on my own" makes sense, but "by train" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: as far as i know, "on my own"means alone or by oneself. what does it mean here?

Comment: It could mean "I am left on my own"; I could imagine somebody saying that while in a difficult situation, and being left alone.

Comment: i would like to answer not too bad.it means the situation is ok for me, just a little busy.

Comment: This question seems like it's designed to trick you.  If someone *actually* said this to me, I think there's a fair chance I'd assume they meant to say or type **doing**.

Comment: What @snailboat said. If this is a genuine "multiple choice" question, it was probably set by some peevish pedant taking a pop at what he deplores as an ungrammatical variant of *"How ya **doing**?"*. I think the question has no merit here.

Comment: It also might help to elaborate as to where this *somewhere* that you found the question was. Context is very important!

Answer (score 4):

It is A; the fact people don't know this worries me.

It's a common Australian phrase similar to, "How are you?"

Really, there isn't another answer to this question, as it would be worded, "How are you getting there?" and not "going," as "going" would be the verb.

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that I am an ignorant person from the US and was unaware of this Australian colloquialism.

Comment: I'm not sure why it worries you.  Are you familiar with all the common American slang?  British?  Indian?  In any case, I don't think "How are you going?" qualifies as Standard English.

Answer (score 2):

A and B would be answers for to the question, "How are you **doing**?" not, "How are you **going**?"

As for why "On my own" is better than "By train" – if a person was traveling alone by train, either answer could be appropriate.

I'd like to think that the clues are:

- the word "buddy" (which may suggest friendship? However, if it does, it's a poorly written question, because many folks are more likely to greet a total stranger with a word like "buddy" than a close friend), and
- the follow-on remark, "A little busy, though."

However, neither one of those would suggest "on my own" is more appropriate than "by train" – at least not to me.

One last thought: "On my own" can also mean "I'm single, and I don't have a girlfriend right now." However, it's a bit of a stretch to think someone would answer a question about traveling that way, so, even if that was the case, I still think it's a rather bad question.

Comment: Is that "not" in your final sentence a typo? Personally I think *"On my own"* would be a rather unusual response, since one would normally understand *"How are you going?"* as meaning *"By what **method** are you travelling?"*, rather than *"In what **state, condition** are you travelling?"*

Comment: Fumble: I agree with your comment, so I've edited my answer.